# booleans not shown in 'rostopic echo -p /topic'

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My issue was that a boolean field (bool) in my custom message was displayed when using 'rostopic echo /topic_name' but not when using 'rostopic echo -p /topic_name'.

I want to use the -p option to get a more concise output with 'rostopic echo -p /topic > file.txt'  for use with Matlab. (The time it takes for Matlab to parse file.txt is significant, which is why I want the -p option)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33046/booleans-not-shown-in-%27rostopic-echo--p-/topic%27/) by [Dr. Love](https://answers.ros.org/users/2285/dr.-love/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Ticketed](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3948)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0